# How to store for an OTP for a specific amount time before making it invalid

Tags: javascript

I am working on building a simple in house OTP system for my website. I need the value generated in my function to only be stored and valid for only a few minutes. Don't know how to change the return value to make it render the expired OTP as invalid.

```
async function OTP() {
    // Storing digits variable
    var digits = '0123456789';
    let OTP = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        OTP += digits[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
    }
    return OTP;
}
```

Comment: There's not enough context here. Typically you'd either store the OTP in a database (or any data storage) alongside with a validity period, or you'd generate something like an encrypted value that encompasses the token along with the validity period.

Comment: Assuming the OTP will be used on client request such as login, you can save two values (OTP key, and its expiry time). When you login you can check if the second key time is more than current time or not.

Comment: You can use redis for this purpose where you can store a value for a definite period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, here is what I have done to solve my issue. Thanks @Tushar Shashi and @apokryfos for the guidance.

```
    async function requestOtp(email: string): Promise<string> {
      // Generate 6 Digit Otp
      const newOtp = security.generateSecureOTP(6);
    
      // Store OTP in firebase.
      const newOtpDoc = new otp();
      newOtpDoc.otp = newOtp;
      await newOtpDoc.addToFirestore().catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("aborted", "Failed to create OTP");
      });
    
      // Send 6 Digit OTP to Email
      const emailText = "Your OTP for is <strong>" + newOtp + "</strong>. It will expire in 6 hours.";
      await sendEmail(email, "OTP for ", emailText);
    
      // Return Verification ID
      return newOtpDoc.verificationId;
    }
    
    // Returns true/false if otp is correct or not.
    async function verifyOtp(otpStr: string, verificationId: string): Promise<boolean> {
      // Try to find verification code in firebase.
      const otpRef = otpsCollection.doc(verificationId);
      const otpDoc = await otpRef.get().catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("aborted", "Failed to verify OTP.");
      });
      if (otpDoc.exists == false) {
        console.error("Could not find OTP within database.");
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("aborted", "Failed to create OTP.");
      }
    
      const currentOtp = otp.fromJSON(otpDoc.data()!);
    
      if (currentOtp.expires < admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("aborted", "OTP has expired.");
      }
    
      return (currentOtp.otp == otpStr);
    }
```